# rvalue reference and move of a local variable

Tags: c++, move, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

In this snippet, I allocate a local object B that I pass to the constructor of another object C which takes it as a rvalue reference. I then put the latter into a container.

When I retrieve C and static_cast its member back to B, the value is incorrect (and valgrind identifies 18 errors!)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class A {
public:
  virtual ~A() {};
};

class B: public A {
public:
  B(int foo) : _foo(foo) {}
  int _foo;
};

class C {
public:
  C(A&& a): _a(std::move(a)) {}
  A&& _a;
};

std::vector<C> v;

void bar() {
  v.emplace_back(B(12));
}

int main() {
  bar();
  C&& c = std::move(v.front());
  std::cout << static_cast<B&&>(c._a)._foo << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

My understanding is that, as C takes a rvalue reference, there should not be any object slicing. I should still be able to retrieve a full B object. Additionally, my understanding (most probably flawed) of `std::move` is that I can 'move' a local variable out of its context and that by taking a rvalue reference, C takes ownership of B.

The output is `39931504` instead of `12`.

Anyone could explain to me what is going on?

Comment: `C` has a rvalue-reference as a member. So it doesn't own anything, it just refers to a variable. That variable is a local variable in the function `bar` which means it is destroyed as soon as the function ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I should still be able to retrieve a full B object.

You would be if it wasn't a temporary that does not exist by the moment control reaches `bar`'s closing brace. You hold a reference in your `C` and a reference to a temporary object can quickly become dangling.

A quick fix is to simply change `C`'s member declaration into `std::unique_ptr<A> a;` and properly initialise it, say, as

```cpp
template<class AChild> C(AChild child)
  : a(std::make_unique<AChild>(std::move(child))) {};
```

(add SFINAE by taste).

Comment: Since OP seems to be wanting the polymorphic behaviour of `B`, making the member into a `std::unique_ptr<A>` seems more appropriate.

Comment: Yes @super, I am trying to avoid object slicing. I guess I don't understand the purpose of rvalue reference then. I tought they were used to transfer ownership of 'temporary' variables. But maybe I am confusing rvalue and local lvalue...

Comment: @LukeSkywalker They can be used to pass a temporary. The problem here is that you pass the temporary all the way to `v`, but once you have a reference to the temporary there you need to actually store it somewhere. If not, it will simply be destroyed.

Comment: @LukeSkywalker don't over-complicate it. Use a reference, if you must, use a pointer. If you find your self writing `&&` outside of a template, stop. You're probably going in the wrong direction. If you still think you're going in the right direction, watch this video and ask yourself if you still think that. https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Standard-Template-Library-STL-/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Standard-Template-Library-STL-9-of-n

Comment: @LukeSkywalker The concept of _trasferring the ownership_ basically works such that you _move-construct_ a new object and pass some rvalue (your temporary) as an argument to move constructor. There is no new object in your case, you just bind a reference to a temporary, which, alone, does not transfer anything anywhere.

Comment: Shouldn't it be ```template<class AChild> C(AChild&& child) : a(std::make_unique<AChild>(std::move(child))) {};``` ? To avoid an unecessary copy?

Comment: @LukeSkywalker It could be if you don't want to accept lvalue refs. Otherwise like this.

Comment: @bipll, that will accept lvalues. Its a forwarding reference inside a template, not a rvalue reference.
@LukeSkywalker Who says the copy is unnecessary? Let the caller decide. If they don't want a copy, they can move their object into the function. As written, anything passed to the function will be left in an unspecified (but valid) state.
Depending on what `C<>` is supposed to do, that could be the expected or unexpected behavior, but again, why not simply let the caller decide?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the reference to `A` in the class `C` (i.e., the data member `_a`) outlives the object it is referring to. This is because the *temporary* `B(12)` in your `bar()` function

```
void bar() {
   v.emplace_back(B(12));
}
```

does not exist after returning from `bar()`. So, the reference to `A` that the class `C` contains becomes a *dangling reference*.

---

Instead of a temporary, you can create a `B` object with the `new` operator:

```
void bar() {
   B* ptr = new B(12);
   v.emplace_back(std::move(*ptr));
}
```

This `B` object doesn't cease to exist when returning from `bar()`, so the reference to `A` in `C` remains valid.

Note that with this approach you need to destroy the object manually:

```
C&& c = std::move(v.front());
// ...
delete &c._a; // destroy object
```

Comment: But needs to be cleaned up later.

Comment: Why are you using raw new and delete in C++ in (almost) 2020?

Comment: @Taekahn to explain the problem without having to change OP's definition of class `C`.